# Adjective for something that is no cause for concern

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective to describe something that does not incite worry, fear, anger, or any other negative emotion. It is no cause for concern of any kind.

Preferably it would be a word or phrase that does not contain a negation and relatively short in length. Obscure words are welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for something active like moderating or just something neutral like indifference?

Comment: If you're not looking for *benign* and synonyms, *trifling* comes to mind if you're looking for synonyms of *inconsequential*.

Comment: @Bookeater something neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if this works for you:

> From MW dictionary:
>
> ***[benign](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benign)***: not causing harm or damage

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there are two questions here - words that do not incite negative emotions like anger or fear, and words that are not justifiable cause for those emotions. "**Benign**", alwayslearning's answer, satisfies the second but not the first - since, I think, there fundamentally are two concepts suggested here.

As for the other, if you're avoiding positive goods like "soothing" or "comforting," I like "**innocuous**" (even if it technically begins with a negative prefix). Strictly it means "harmless" (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/innocuous), but it can carry connotations of not even seeming dangerous.